# Firebase where clause with 'Field.subField' no matching documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using javascript to write a Google Cloud function. In the onWrite function I am trying to retrieve a list of subscriptions from using a where clause on the 'subscription' collection. Each subscription doc looks like this:

[image: Subscription Collection Structure]

I need to use the Ref field under 'ToUser' in the where clause so I can match it with the userRef I obtained from the onWrite cloud function trigger -> 'userRef' which looks like this:

```
let userRef = "/users/0e2qgHKZokSb9l02EywrEmJNhVd2"
```

Here is the js code I have to try and query the subscription collection:

```
// 2. Query subscription collection using above id to 'ToUser'
// for list of subscribers

let subscriptions = db.collection("subscriptions")

let subscribers = subscriptions.where('ToUser.Ref', '==', userRef).get()
.then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
        return;
    }  
    var subs = []

    snapshot.forEach( sub => {
        console.log("Sub : " + JSON.stringify(sub.FromUser.Ref) )
        //subscribers.append(sub.val().FromUser)
    })
    return subs
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

The result of the call to `.get().then()` is snapshot is empty and the `console.log('No matching documents.')` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing to a reference, you should pass in an actual `DocumentReference` object.

So:

```
let userRef = db.doc("/users/0e2qgHKZokSb9l02EywrEmJNhVd2")
let subscriptions = db.collection("subscriptions")

let subscribers = subscriptions.where('ToUser.Ref', '==', userRef).get()
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you Frank!

Comment: I did upvote and yes, I do not have enough rep. Okay cool, I will check that out.